# delete multiple rows with checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have the following jquery code to delete multiple rows of table:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.delete").click(function(){
        page=$(this).attr("href");
        ids=new Array()
        a=0;
        $("input.chk:checked").each(function(){
            ids[a]=$(this).val();
            a++;
        })

        if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")){

                el=$(this)
                $.ajax({
                    url:page,
                    data:"id="+ids,
                    type:"GET",
                    success:function(res)
                    {
                        if(res==1)
                        {
                            $("input.chk:checked").each(function(){
                                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
        return false;
    })
})
```

checkbox (value with name question_id is ok, the checkbox is inside a while loop):

```
<input name="chk[]" class="chk" type="checkbox" value="'<?php echo $row1['question_id'];?>'" />
```

delete link (outside of loop):

```
<a href="delete_quiz_questions.php" class="delete">delete</a>
```

and the php page to delete the records:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include('connect_db.php');

   $delete_id = $_GET['id'];

   $id = count($delete_id);

   if (count($id) > 0){
       foreach ($delete_id as $id_d){
           $sql = "DELETE FROM quiz_questions WHERE id_questions ='$id_d' AND id_quiz ='".$_SESSION['quiz_id']."'";
           $delete = mysql_query($sql);
       }
   }


?>
```

when i click in href button to delete record show me this message

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\diplomatiki\delete_quiz_questions.php on line 5

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\diplomatiki\delete_quiz_questions.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined variable: delete in C:\wamp\www\diplomatiki\delete_quiz_questions.php on line 18
```

can you help me please??

the php page to send the data

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_questions WHERE id_quiz='".$quiz_id."' ");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    $index = 1;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id ='".$row['id_questions']."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){

    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {

   $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_".$row1['type']." WHERE id_question='".$row1['question_id']."' LIMIT 1");
   if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){
   $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $index++; ?> </td>
      <td><input name="chk[]" class="chk" type="checkbox" value="'<?php echo $row1['question_id'];?>'" /></td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['type']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row2['question']; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php  }}

    }


}
echo '<input type="hidden" name="quiz_id" id="quiz_id" style="text-align: center" value="' . $quiz_id . '" size=5/>';

?>

  </tbody>
</table>
<caption><a href="delete_quiz_questions.php" class="delete">delete</a></caption>

<?php } else echo 'sorry'; ?>
```

Comment: How will convert `Javascript` array to `PHP` array

Comment: it seems that you haven't understood some principles:
-> $_GET[...] gives the parameter from an url;<a href="delete_quiz_questions.php" ...> doesn't have a parameter so the index is not set; what you'd have to do is sthg. like <a href="delete_quiz_questions.php?id=123" ...>

also not that you should NEVER EVER do what you did in your SQL statement. it's almost an invitation to an SQL-injection:
"DELETE FROM quiz_questions WHERE id_questions ='$id_d' <- which is the param from the URL; be sure to escape it: mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET["id"]); as you can see; also use mysqli...

Comment: yes i'am new.. i try it!

Comment: Below is the answer for you.

Comment: @sandip The data he is passing is correct. Don't confuse him. No need of brackets

Answer (score 1):

You must use `explode` to convert the ID string to an `Array`.

```
$delete_id = explode(",", $_GET['id'])
$id = count($delete_id);
if (count($id) > 0)
```

Initially you must do this.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
```

So You will not get any `Notice` or `Warning`

```
session_start();
include('connect_db.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $delete_id = explode(",", $_GET['id'])

   $id = count($delete_id);

   if (count($id) > 0)
   {
       foreach ($delete_id as $id_d)
       {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM quiz_questions WHERE id_questions ='$id_d' AND id_quiz ='".$_SESSION['quiz_id']."'";
                $delete = mysql_query($sql);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: sahal now i have two messages: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\diplomatiki\delete_quiz_questions.php on line 21 and Notice: Undefined index: quiz_id in C:\wamp\www\diplomatiki\delete_quiz_questions.php on line 27

Comment: `$_SESSION['quiz_id']` I donno how it is coming

Comment: if i send quiz_id like this? echo '<input type="hidden" name="quiz_id" id="quiz_id" value="' . $quiz_id . '" />'; can you change me the code of jquery to send and quiz_id with get?

Comment: Do like this in `data:"id="+ids,` you can modify to `data:"id="+ids+"&quiz_id="+$('#quiz_id').val(),` and instead of `$_SESSION` use `$_GET` for quiz_id

Comment: Undefined index: quiz_id in C:\wamp\www\diplomatiki\delete_quiz_questions.php on line 4 and the get[id] not pass!!

Comment: Past me you jquery and php here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21949/discussion-between-mitel-castro-and-sahal)

Comment: I don't have access to chat domain.

Comment: <?php
session_start();
include('connect_db.php');


if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $quiz_id = $_GET['quiz_id'];
   $delete_id = explode(",", $_GET['id']);
echo $delete_id;

   $id = count($delete_id);

   if (count($id) > 0)
   {
       foreach ($delete_id as $id_d)
       {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM quiz_questions WHERE id_questions ='$id_d' AND id_quiz ='".$quiz_id."'";
                $delete = mysql_query($sql);
       }
   }
} else {echo "nothing";}
?>

Comment: $(function(){
 $("a.delete").click(function(){
  page=$(this).attr("href");
  ids=new Array()
  a=0;
  $("input.chk:checked").each(function(){
   ids[a]=$(this).val();
   a++;
  })

  if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")){

    el=$(this)
    $.ajax({
     url:page,
     data:"id="+ids+"&quiz_id="+$('#quiz_id').val(),
     type:"GET",
     success:function(res)
     {
      if(res==1)
      {
       $("input.chk:checked").each(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       })
      }
     }
    })
  }
  return false;
 })
})

Comment: Your code is correct, can you check `hidden field` is storing the value of `quiz_id`.

Comment: $quiz_id is ok into hidden button

Comment: here's the solution $("a.delete_questions").live('click',function(){  and url i put it directly to function and not in href

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must check session quiz_id is exist or not.If exist you should check this session assigned any value.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: quiz_id in C:\wamp\www\diplomatiki\delete_quiz_questions.php on line 4.. i have problem with that.. and my page refresh when click to delete and send me to delete_quiz_questions page

Comment: you just put an alert box in success:function(res)

Comment: the problem is very big.. nothing send.. id or quiz_id and the page refresh

Comment: problem is your ajax not working ,may be beacause of jquery conflict

Comment: Ajax works fine. Don't blindly give answers. Understand the problem first

Comment: but the page refresh.. im in page http://localhost/diplomatiki/index3.php#item3_section2 and show me http://localhost/diplomatiki/delete_quiz_questions.php in url

Comment: @MitelCastro how can i get localhost page.very difficult to answer

Comment: if ajax works fine then how the page refresh ? $_SESSION['quiz_id'] may be empty

Comment: @MitelCastro remove the `href` of anchor tag :(. Replace`delete_quiz_questions.php` with `javascript:void(0)` in `<a href=''`. That is the reason why page refresh. This is like we are teaching you. This is not fare. @Preethy He was telling like he is getting notice bla bla. So i thought code works. See the above comments.

Comment: i'am new and you are my teacher.. can you change the jquery appropriate to send values in page delete_quiz_questions please?

Comment: here's the solution $("a.delete_questions").live('click',function(){  and url i put it directly to function and not in href